# 10000's+ UI elements, bind or draw?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am drawing a header for a timeline control.
It looks like this:
[image]

I go to 0.01 millisecond per line, so for a 10 minute timeline I am looking at drawing 60000 lines + 6000 labels.
This takes a while, ~10 seconds.
I would like to offload this from the UI thread.
My code is currently:

```
private void drawHeader()
{
  Header.Children.Clear();
  switch (viewLevel)
  {
    case ViewLevel.MilliSeconds100:
        double hWidth = Header.Width;
        this.drawHeaderLines(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 10), 100, 5, hWidth);

        //Was looking into background worker to off load UI

        //backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

        //backgroundWorker.DoWork += delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        //                               {
        //                                   this.drawHeaderLines(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 10), 100, 5, hWidth);
        //                               };
        //backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        break;
    }
}

private void drawHeaderLines(TimeSpan timeStep, int majorEveryXLine, int distanceBetweenLines, double headerWidth)
{
var currentTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
const int everyXLine100 = 10;
double currentX = 0;
var currentLine = 0;
while (currentX < headerWidth)
{
    var l = new Line
                {
                    ToolTip = currentTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.fff"),
                    StrokeThickness = 1,
                    X1 = 0,
                    X2 = 0,
                    Y1 = 30,
                    Y2 = 25
                };
    if (((currentLine % majorEveryXLine) == 0) && currentLine != 0)
    {
        l.StrokeThickness = 2;
        l.Y2 = 15;
        var textBlock = new TextBlock
                            {
                                Text = l.ToolTip.ToString(),
                                FontSize = 8,
                                FontFamily = new FontFamily("Tahoma"),
                                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255))
                            };

        Canvas.SetLeft(textBlock, (currentX - 22));
        Canvas.SetTop(textBlock, 0);
        Header.Children.Add(textBlock);
    }

    if ((((currentLine % everyXLine100) == 0) && currentLine != 0)
        && (currentLine % majorEveryXLine) != 0)
    {
        l.Y2 = 20;
        var textBlock = new TextBlock
                            {
                                Text = string.Format(".{0}", TimeSpan.Parse(l.ToolTip.ToString()).Milliseconds),
                                                            FontSize = 8,
                                                            FontFamily = new FontFamily("Tahoma"),
                                                            Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(192, 192, 192))
                            };

        Canvas.SetLeft(textBlock, (currentX - 8));
        Canvas.SetTop(textBlock, 8);
        Header.Children.Add(textBlock);
    }
    l.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255));
    Header.Children.Add(l);
    Canvas.SetLeft(l, currentX);

    currentX += distanceBetweenLines;
    currentLine++;
    currentTime += timeStep;
}
}
```

I had looked into BackgroundWorker, except you can't create UI elements on a non-UI thread.

Is it possible at all to do drawHeaderLines in a non-UI thread?

Could I use data binding for drawing the lines?
Would this help with UI responsiveness?

I would imagine I can use databinding, but the Styling is probably beyond my current WPF ability (coming from winforms and trying to learn what all these style objects are and binding them).

Would anyone be able to supply a starting point for tempting this out? Or Google a tutorial that would get me started?

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?  Using 4.5 this can be made to be a fair bit simpler.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Is this for on on-screen painting? Does it make sense to draw 60000 parallel lines on 1980 screen columns? Quite a lot of lines will probably be drawn one over the other or will be invisible. What I mean is that you could possibly adjust the number of your drawn lines so that the effect is still visually acceptable. Even 1980 lines would look like a block on a HD display so you need much less than that.

Comment: *If* performance is what you seek (i.e. you are building a sequencer or something), you might want to stick with GDI+ as things like this aren't exactly one of WPF's strengths. You would override `OnPaint`, use the `ClipRectangle` of the event args to get the part of the timeline which needs to be drawn, and then calculate and draw each entity within that region manually. Not wanting to force you away from WPF, this is just a suggestion.

Comment: @dialer not true. WPF uses hardware acceleration as opposed to gdi whatever. The right way to do this is by not creating the UIElements in code, but making an ItemsControl and a ViewModel representing the values. Will outperform gdi or winforms or whatever crappy past-century technology by a factor of 10 any day.

Comment: @HighCore: I beg to differ, as one who's made tower defence games in both GDI+ and WPF on a really slow laptop :D Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @minitech What he's trying to do is not a game. It is an immovable ItemsControl which only requires re-rendering when the user moves the scrollbar.

Comment: @minitech while I might agree that WPF is not best-suited for games, which require a hell of a lot of continuous movement, that's not what we're talking about. I also don't think winforms is any better in that arena.

Comment: @HighCore: But when one is moving the scrollbar, all the lines and text are moving at once - it's not all that different. Only the draw times matter. But that's probably not a good reason to choose one over the other - with an inefficient way of doing it, it'll be slow either way, and vice-versa. The problem lies elsewhere :) (And if direct drawing is faster, all you have to do in WPF is override `OnRender`, right?)

Comment: @minitech that's right. but then you have `ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrolling`. And your point of 'only the draw times matter' confirm my statement that WPF can outperform everything else because of DirectX enabled hardware acceleration

Comment: Isn't there a way in WPF to be able to add a bunch of controls at once and then do the redraw in one show. Wouldn't adding them one at a time do things less efficiently?

Comment: @HighCore that is a misconception. WPF does not mean that everything is offloaded to the GPU. XNA and WPF still heavily utilize the CPU. Using an ItemsControl for 60k items is extremely heavy weight as opposed to drawing a few lines, which is absolutely nothing for a modern CPU. Have you used CUDA or OpenCL yet? If yes, you'll undoubtetly have noticed that the borderline at which GPU calculations become more efficient than CPU calculations is ridiculously high due to overhead. I have created two comparison programs. GDI+ is smooth, WPF has 11 sec startup time and window resizing flickers.

Comment: @dialer that has a lot of sense. I have reconsidered my point of view. However, it is still easier in WPF to improve performance because it has built-in UI Virtualization. He doesn't actually need to draw the 60k items on screen because there is a scroll bar and from what can be seen in the sample picture only 1/4 of the total scrolling area is actually being shown on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I had put this on the back burner for a little but.

But I think I have come up with a solution.

To use DrawingVisual and DrawingContext.

This blog post helped me quite a bit: [Simple WPF 2D Graphics: DrawingVisual](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2010/11/28/simple-wpf-2d-graphics-drawingvisual.aspx)

First we need to get our Visual class (note this code has been slapped together, cleaning is a good idea):

```
public class MyVisualHost : FrameworkElement
{
private readonly VisualCollection children;

public MyVisualHost(int width)
{
    children = new VisualCollection(this);

    var visual = new DrawingVisual();
    children.Add(visual);

    var currentTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    const int everyXLine100 = 10;
    double currentX = 0;
    var currentLine = 0;
    double distanceBetweenLines = 5;
    TimeSpan timeStep = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 10);
    int majorEveryXLine = 100;

    var grayBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(192, 192, 192));
    grayBrush.Freeze();
    var grayPen = new Pen(grayBrush, 2);
    var whitePen = new Pen(Brushes.White, 2);
    grayPen.Freeze();
    whitePen.Freeze();

    using (var dc = visual.RenderOpen())
    {
        while (currentX < width)
        {
            if (((currentLine % majorEveryXLine) == 0) && currentLine != 0)
            {
                dc.DrawLine(whitePen, new Point(currentX, 30), new Point(currentX, 15));

                var text = new FormattedText(
                    currentTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.fff"),
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                    FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                    new Typeface("Tahoma"),
                    8,
                    grayBrush);

                dc.DrawText(text, new Point((currentX - 22), 0));
            }
            else if ((((currentLine % everyXLine100) == 0) && currentLine != 0)
                        && (currentLine % majorEveryXLine) != 0)
            {
                dc.DrawLine(grayPen, new Point(currentX, 30), new Point(currentX, 20));

                var text = new FormattedText(
                    string.Format(".{0}", currentTime.Milliseconds),
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                    FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                    new Typeface("Tahoma"),
                    8,
                    grayBrush);
                dc.DrawText(text, new Point((currentX - 8), 8));
            }
            else
            {
                dc.DrawLine(grayPen, new Point(currentX, 30), new Point(currentX, 25));
            }

            currentX += distanceBetweenLines;
            currentLine++;
            currentTime += timeStep;
        }
    }
}

// Provide a required override for the VisualChildrenCount property.
protected override int VisualChildrenCount { get { return children.Count; } }

// Provide a required override for the GetVisualChild method.
protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= children.Count)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }

    return children[index];
}
}
```

Next we need our binding:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderDrawingVisualProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderDrawingVisual", typeof(MyVisualHost), typeof(MainWindow));

public MyVisualHost VisualHost
{
    get { return (MyVisualHost)GetValue(HeaderDrawingVisualProperty); }
    set { SetValue(HeaderDrawingVisualProperty, value); }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Canvas x:Name="Header" Background="#FF2D2D30" Grid.Row="0">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding HeaderDrawingVisual}" />
</Canvas>
```

Then just set in code:

```
Header.Width = 50000;
VisualHost = new MyVisualHost(50000);
```

My testing showed, using a width of 50000 with this new method, I saw a great increase!

```
Old way Total Milliseconds: 277.061
New way Total Milliseconds: 13.9982
Old way Total Milliseconds: 518.4632
New way Total Milliseconds: 12.9423
Old way Total Milliseconds: 479.1846
New way Total Milliseconds: 23.4987
Old way Total Milliseconds: 477.1366
New way Total Milliseconds: 12.6469
Old way Total Milliseconds: 481.3118
New way Total Milliseconds: 12.9678
```

Time is less the first time because items have to be cleared when rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

So, as you have said, all of this work needs to be done in the UI thread; you can't just do it in a background thread.

However, running a very long loop doing a lot of UI modifications in the UI thread blocks the UI thread, so clearly we can't do that.

They key here is that you need to break up what you're doing into many smaller units of work, and then do all of those small units of work in the UI thread.  The UI thread is doing just as much work as before (possibly even a tad more, due to the overhead of managing all of this) but it allows other things (such as mouse move/click events, key presses, etc.) to happen in-between those tasks.

Here is a simple example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TaskScheduler uiContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = i.ToString() });
            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiContext);
        }
    });
}
```

First we grab the UI context while in the UI thread, then we start a new thread in the background that will be responsible for starting up all of our little tasks.  Here you would have the start of your loop.  (You may want to exract this out to another method, since yours isn't as simple.)  Then, immediately inside of the loop start a new task, and have that task started in the UI's context.  Inside of that task you can then place the entire body of what was in your loop.  By `await`ing on that task you ensure that each one is scheduled as a continuation of the previous, so they all run in order.  If the order doesn't matter (which is unlikely, but possible) then you don't need to await at all.

If you need a C# 4.0 version of this you could keep one `Task` out of the loop, and in each iteration wire up a new task as a continuation of the previous, and then set "itself" as that task.  It would be messier though.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a proof of concept but I think you could use ListView virtualization.  Rather than text just have a collection of images (one image for each 10 lines).  With virtualiztion it only renders what is in display.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Numbers}" Width="100" Height="500">
        <ListView.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="90" CenterX="150" CenterY="150"/>
        </ListView.RenderTransform> 
    </ListView>
</Grid>




public List<string> Numbers
{
    get
    {
        List<string> numbers = new List<string>();
        for (UInt16 i=1; i < 60000; i++)
        {
            numbers.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        return numbers;
    }
}
```