# Rendering images fails when image over 40,000 wide

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmap, png

I am trying to create a time scale like in Adobe Premiere like this:
[image]
But, I have to go to down to 0.01 second increments.

My timeline control looks like: 
[image]

**UPDATE:**
I have used @Sten Petrov suggestion and used a `VisualBrush`.

But now I am stuck on how to implement the `Label` for the Seconds.

My new code (containing control can change):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="680.839">
<Grid Background="Black">

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
        <ScrollViewer.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="False" UseLayoutRounding="True">
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <VisualBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,5,30" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,0,5,30" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
                                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                    <Line Stroke="Coral" StrokeThickness="2" X1="0" X2="0" Y1="25" Y2="30" UseLayoutRounding="True" />
                                </VisualBrush.Visual>
                            </VisualBrush>
                        </Grid.Background>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Margin="50,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" UseLayoutRounding="True">
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <VisualBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,50,30" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,0,50,30" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
                                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                    <Line Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" X1="0" X2="0" Y1="20" Y2="30" UseLayoutRounding="True" />
                                </VisualBrush.Visual>
                            </VisualBrush>
                        </Grid.Background>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="False" Height="30" UseLayoutRounding="True" >
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <VisualBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,500,30" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,0,500,30" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
                                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="500" UseLayoutRounding="True">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="21*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="8" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="1" Height="9" Content=".100" Foreground="White"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="8" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="2" Height="9" Content=".200" Foreground="White"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="8" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="3" Height="9" Content=".300" Foreground="White"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="8" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="4" Height="9" Content=".400" Foreground="White"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="8" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="5" Height="9" Content=".500" Foreground="White"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="8" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="6" Height="9" Content=".600" Foreground="White"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="8" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="7" Height="9" Content=".700" Foreground="White"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="8" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="8" Height="9" Content=".800" Foreground="White"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="8" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="9" Height="9" Content=".900" Foreground="White"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </VisualBrush.Visual>
                            </VisualBrush>
                        </Grid.Background>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="False" Height="30" UseLayoutRounding="True" Margin="500,0,0,0" >
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <VisualBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,500,30" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,0,500,30" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
                                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                    <Line Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="2" X1="0" X2="0" Y1="10" Y2="30" UseLayoutRounding="True" />
                                </VisualBrush.Visual>
                            </VisualBrush>
                        </Grid.Background>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="False" Height="30" UseLayoutRounding="True" Margin="491,0,0,0" >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="7"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="23"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!--Need something here-->
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="8" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="0" Height="9" Content="00:00" Foreground="White"/>
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ScrollViewer.ContentTemplate>
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

**/UPDATE**

I go to 0.01 seconds per line, so for a 10 minute timeline I am looking at drawing 60000 lines + 6000 labels.

I asked a prior question on this before: [10000's+ UI elements, bind or draw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314889/10000s-ui-elements-bind-or-draw)

Originally I was drawing lines directly on a `Canvas`.
Then I went to using a `VisualHost` because it is supposed to be lighter weight.

Well it isn't light enough.

I have a `MediaElement` that plays a video and the Timeline scrolls in sync with the video position. A `ScrollViewer` wraps my Timeline and does `.ScrollToHorizontalOffset` about every 10ms.

If my Timeline was over something like 3 minutes the video shutters.
I assume this is because a `VisualHost` still has all the Framework Elements in it and the scrolling causes them to be re-validated.

So now I am trying to generate a `Image` to display, I think that should be lighter yet.

Am I wrong in this assumption?

Now I am facing issues with making the Timeline into an `Image`.

I could not Render an entire Timeline to a Image so I am 'Chunking' it.  I was hitting `Exceptions` about Image size being to big.

On to my code:
This is my main entry point.

```
public void RenderHeaderPicture()
{
    const int ChunkSize = 5000;
    var bitmapFrames = new List<BitmapFrame>();

    // generates X number of DrawingVisual's based on ChunkSize
    List<DrawingVisual> visuals = generateHeaderVisualChunks(
        AppViewModel.TimelineViewModel.HeaderWidth, ChunkSize, TimelineViewModel.ViewLevel.Level1);

    for (var i = 0; i < visuals.Count; i++)
    {
        var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(ChunkSize, 30, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        renderTargetBitmap.Render(visuals[i]);

        //test to make sure image good
        saveHeaderSegmentAsPng(string.Format("headerSeg{0}.png", i), renderTargetBitmap);

        bitmapFrames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));
    }

    // put the frames back together now
    var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
    using (var drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bitmapFrames.Count; i++)
        {
            drawingContext.DrawImage(bitmapFrames[i], new Rect(i * ChunkSize, 0, bitmapFrames[i].PixelWidth, 30));
        }
        drawingContext.Close();
    }

    var newBmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(AppViewModel.TimelineViewModel.HeaderWidth, 30, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    newBmp.Render(drawingVisual);

    AppViewModel.TimelineViewModel.HeaderImageSource = newBmp;
}
```

Here is the code that creates the `DrawingVisual's`

```
private List<DrawingVisual> generateHeaderVisualChunks(int width, int chunkSize, TimelineViewModel.ViewLevel level) 
{ 
    var ret = new List<DrawingVisual>();

    var currentTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    var timeStep = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, (int)level);
    var currentLine = 0;

    const double DistanceBetweenLines = 5;
    const int TenthOfSecondLine = 10;
    const int SecondLine = 100;

    int iterations = (width / chunkSize);
    int remainder = width % chunkSize; //not doing anything with yet

    var grayBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(192, 192, 192));
    var grayPen = new Pen(grayBrush, 2);
    var whitePen = new Pen(Brushes.Purple, 2);

    grayBrush.Freeze();
    grayPen.Freeze();
    whitePen.Freeze();

    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        var visual = new DrawingVisual();
        using (var dc = visual.RenderOpen())
        {
            double currentX = 0;

            if (i > 0)
            {
                currentLine--;
                currentTime -= timeStep;
            }

            while (currentX <= chunkSize)
            {
                if (((currentLine % SecondLine) == 0) && currentLine != 0)
                {
                    dc.DrawLine(whitePen, new Point(currentX, 30), new Point(currentX, 15));
                    FormattedText text = null;
                    double tempX = currentX;
                    switch (level)
                    {
                        case TimelineViewModel.ViewLevel.Level1:
                            text = new FormattedText(
                                    currentTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.fff"),
                                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                    FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                                    new Typeface("Tahoma"),
                                    8,
                                    grayBrush);
                            break;
                    }

                    dc.DrawText(text, new Point((tempX - 22), 0));
                }
                else if ((((currentLine % TenthOfSecondLine) == 0) && currentLine != 0)
                            && (currentLine % SecondLine) != 0)
                {
                    dc.DrawLine(grayPen, new Point(currentX, 30), new Point(currentX, 20));

                    FormattedText text = null;
                    switch (level)
                    {
                        case TimelineViewModel.ViewLevel.Level1:
                            text = new FormattedText(
                                    string.Format(".{0}", currentTime.Milliseconds),
                                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                    FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                                    new Typeface("Tahoma"),
                                    8,
                                    grayBrush);
                            break;
                    }

                    dc.DrawText(text, new Point((currentX - 8), 8));
                }
                else
                {
                    dc.DrawLine(grayPen, new Point(currentX, 30), new Point(currentX, 25));
                }

                currentX += DistanceBetweenLines;
                currentLine++;
                currentTime += timeStep;
            }
        }
        ret.Add(visual);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Save png segment:

```
private static void saveHeaderSegmentAsPng(string fileName, RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap)
{
    var pngBitmapEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();

    pngBitmapEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        pngBitmapEncoder.Save(fileStream);
        fileStream.Flush();
        fileStream.Close();
    }
}
```

All of my png segments are rendered correctly in their separate files.
And my Timeline is rendered correctly until I go over 1:20 then things break.

See:
[image]

It's like the Image is smeared or something.
Anyone know what is going on with this?

Thanks

Comment: "Am I wrong in this assumption?" Yes. "Well it isn't light enough." Why isn't it light enough? Perhaps you should think about virtualization, only draw whats visible instead of everything. Without knowing how you did it before, we can't fix it. But the image thing is definitely not lightweight.

Comment: I used a `VisualHost` before,  generateHeaderVisualChunks is what I would use but without Chunking it.

It is not light enough because the `VisualHost` would cause my video to skip.  My `ScrollViewer` keeps the current video Position centered in the `ScrollViewer`  so the `ScrollViewer` is scrolling every ~10ms.

Comment: One thing I noticed in generateHeaderVisualChunks, Your pens, brushs, and typefaces should be created outside of the function, perhaps static, no need to put pressure on the GC by creating new ones, they don't change. I also wonder if you could generate a larger than whats visible into your visual, allow the scrollviewer to move it, detect when you're getting close to the end, and then regenerate. In other words, break it up into larger chunks so that you're not doing the heavy lifting quite as often.

Comment: Does even the Jumbotron have a width of 40,000 pixels? Why are you trying to squeeze so much information into each pixel?

Comment: "Does even the Jumbotron have a width of 40,000 pixels? Why are you trying to squeeze so much information into each pixel?"  Because it is a sliding timeline scale.  I am trying to recreate a timeline like in Adobe Premiere.  http://cdn.freedownloadsplace.com/screenshots-650/Adobe-Premiere-3.png  But, I have to go down to 0.01 seconds increments.

Comment: Guess what Pieter means is that no matter your timeline's resolution, the average screen will display about 2000 pixels, at most. You need to generate the visible part, not the entire timeline.

Comment: @jpiccolo you may also want to pre-render all the possible video/audio/whatever frames you're planning on showing in your app since you've taken the pre-generated approach. Also pre-generate all possible output. Now you don't even have to have an app that pre-generates its UI as images, problem solved :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm waiting for the day when my living room will have a TV with horizontal resolution that will require something like your approach.

Scrap this whole piece of code you just demoed here, it will never become usable *and* maintainable, you could only manage to squeeze one of these out of it.

Then learn about [VisualBrush](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/visual-brush-in-wpf/), there are plenty of tutorials out there, it can repeat your visual template, no need of PNGs and it will scale better when screen resolution changes (up to 40001px wide)

For the numbers that appear above the marks there are a million different approaches, some of them can be combined with the visual brush mentioned above, such as a user control that represents your timeline unit (the space between two larger marks). Now place several of them in a grid (stackpanel, canvas... as you wish) and adjust (dynamically) their offset and labels - all of a sudden you can represent an infinite timeline with 10 controls on the screen.